# Is methanol optically active?

Tags: optical-properties

Strictly on theoretical basis, not based on experimental results.

I can very well be wrong, but I think that methanol should be 
optically inactive because it has a plane of symmetry passing through it.
My teacher however insists that it is optically active as you can create two non-superimposable mirror images out of it.

Who is correct and why?

Comment: You can create two STATIC images of methanol that are non-superimposable mirror images but that does not make methanol optically active. Every conformation has a mirror image, i.e., a racemate, or a plane of symmetry. Both conditions lead to a lack of optical activity. Consider changing classes.

Comment: The -OH group is pretty much free to rotate around. If not for this fact, your teacher would be _wrong just once_.

Comment: Is your teacher an engineer?

Comment: Thanks @user55119 for your answer. I however for some reason can't tick your answer because I found it helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to sum up what has already been pointed out in the comments: Methanol can have infinite conformations in free space due to free rotation of the C-H and C-OH sigma bonds. Hence, for any particular spatial conformation you can think of for the molecule, it can always develop a perfect mirror image for the same *almost instantly*(in case you are wondering about some time lag between them) as conformers are in chemical equilibrium.

So what this essentially means is that, suppose some conformation **A** of methanol has polarized light in some direction (assuming the right-handed coordinate system, let's say the positive X direction) in some fashion(let's say circularly polarized, clockwise). Then, this particular interference pattern of light will be internally compensated by a conformation **B** of the molecule which will circularly polarize the light in the anticlockwise direction in the negative X direction. So, the emergent light ray will appear to be unpolarized for the observer